Why Kaniko with using git context cannot use file from out of git contex?
I am using Kaniko in GitLab CI to build Docker images. Kaniko doesn't directly support Git operations, so I need to switch to another branch or commit within the Kaniko image. This allows me to use Git context for building the image.
However, I face an issue when I need to include artifacts from previous GitLab CI jobs that are outside of the Git context. Kaniko restricts access to files outside of the Git context when using Git context for building Docker images.
How can I include files or directories located outside of the Git context in Kaniko when building a Dockerfile?
